# Building a simple MediaPlayer with Kotlin in Android Studio. Can not get URL dataSource to stream

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make a simple radio streaming app with Kotlin in Android studio.

This is my code. When i press play on the emulator the app crashes.

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.media.MediaPlayer
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import java.lang.Exception



class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

     var mp: MediaPlayer?=null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }


 fun playRadio (view: View) {
     mp = MediaPlayer()


     try {
         mp!!.setDataSource("https://s2.radio.co/sdf9aeb4e9/listen")
         mp!!.prepare()
         mp!!.start()

     } catch (ex:Exception){}


}

    fun pauseButton (view: View){
        try {
            mp!!.stop()

        } catch (ex:Exception){}


    }


}
```

Hit a bit of a wall with it. Any help greatly appreciated.

errors in the `Logcat` are as follows:

```
2019-11-27 17:13:34.336 21050-21050/com.example.myapplication V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@c7f0ecc): Cookies: null
2019-11-27 17:13:34.348 21050-21082/com.example.myapplication V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieManager created: java.net.CookieManager@663a515
2019-11-27 17:13:34.348 21050-21082/com.example.myapplication V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection(android.media.MediaHTTPService@c7f0ecc): cookieHandler: java.net.CookieManager@663a515 Cookies: null
2019-11-27 17:13:34.360 21050-21082/com.example.myapplication D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2019-11-27 17:14:04.837 21050-21082/com.example.myapplication E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -2147483648)
2019-11-27 17:14:04.841 21050-21050/com.example.myapplication I/Choreographer: Skipped 1830 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: Can you show what the errors are in the Logcat ?

Comment: I have edited the post to include ```Logcat``` errors at the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok it seems for some reason it is working as posted on some emulators but not others. Nexus 5: works, Pixel 3a: works, Pixel 2: does not work.

Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: However it won't work when trying to stream from a http link and not https.
```"http://s3.voscast.com:9532"``` is a no go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play the songs from your device , here is the codes , remember play is
a button to trigger the song play. Hope you goodluck

```kotlin
     fun getURI(){
        val path: String =
            Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC)
                .getAbsolutePath()
        val directory = File(path)
        try {
            val mSongsList: Array<File> = directory.listFiles()
            val mUri = Uri.fromFile(mSongsList[0])
            Log.v("MainActivity", mUri.toString())
            mp!!.reset()
            mp!!.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)
            mp!!.setDataSource(this, mUri)
            mp!!.prepare()
            play!!.setOnClickListener {
                mp!!.start()
            }

        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```